# who does npm install of webpack-dev-server require '-g'?

Tags: node.js, webpack, visual-studio-code

Trying to run "webpack-dev-server --open" from VSCode bash terminal. Error: webpack-dev-server not found

Why do I have to do the install with '-g'? If I install local, I get the not found error. In this case, do I have to modify the path to pick up the local install?

```
npm install webpack-dev-server -g
```

Answer (score 0):

When you install `webpack-dev-server` locally in your project, you can run it with `npx`:

```sh
npx webpack-dev-server --open
```

Or:

```sh
./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --open
```

You can also add a script in `package.json`:

```
scripts: {
  dev: "webpack-dev-server --open"
}
```

Then run `npm run dev`.

There's no need to install it globally, which is not recommended.

Comment: I already have it in package.json but thanks. I installed with a -g to skirt the issue. I just don't understand why this module requires path resolution on a local install when other modules don't seem to have the same problem.